# Can't choose the correct SQLite library to connect to my own Signal Desktop DB

Tags: c#, .net, signals, sqlcipher

My goal is to make queries to my own Signal Desktop app similarly to DB Browser SQLCipher. I tried to investigate some libraries but had no success. I guess my problem is to find the correct library and generate the correct connection string for it. Requirements are Windows 10 OS and C#. Thanks in advance.

Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core and SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_e_sqlcipher